# How to use \lstset only on one paragraph of code?

Tags: listings

If i use this command

```
\lstset{ 
    numbersep=8pt, 
    frame = single, 
    language=pascal, 
    framexrightmargin=-10cm}
```

i get all the paragraphs using \lstlistings in a box and i don't need that. I need to specifically have only certain code paragraphs in a box.

Comment: \begingroup before and \endgroup after your paragraph (lstset between).

Comment: You're the man!

Answer (score 4):

Just to answer this: LaTeX has a kind of scopes as most programming languages have too. That means you can make changes "local". `\lstset` supports this behavior.

To change one paragraph you can put it in a group like:

```
{
\lstset{frame=single}
your paragraph here
}
```

or

```
\begingroup
\lstset{frame=single}
your paragraph here
\endgroup
```